# Faster Metapost SVG Output with TeX?

Tags: metapost, svg

I am generating some diagrams with METAPOST.  I need the output in SVG format.  My labels are generated by
calls to LaTeX via `Tex.mp` and its `TEX` METAPOST definition (also called a macro).

My complaint:  it is pretty slow to constantly write stuff to a file and fire off an instance of `latex`.

Is there a faster way to achieve the same result?  (As I recall, I can use METAPOST inside a TeX document with
the package `luamplib`, which is fast, but it generates PDF, not SVG.)

Minimal example:

```
prologues:=3;
input TEX;

outputformat := "svg";
outputtemplate:="%j.%{outputformat}";

string texpre;
% texpre = "%&latex" & char(10) &
texpre = 
  "\documentclass{article}" & char(10) &
  "\begin{document}  " & char(10);

TEXPRE(texpre);
TEXPOST("\end{document}");

beginfig(1)
  draw fullcircle scaled 1in;
  string l;
  l = "Foo";
  dotlabel.bot(TEX("Label is " & l), origin);
endfig;
end
```

Comment: Could you make a small example where you use `TEX.mp`?

Comment: @egreg, better?

Comment: Well, the output I get is completely mangled.

Comment: @egreg, I am using MetaPost 1.802 (TeX Live 2013/W32TeX) with command line: `mpost --numbersystem=double --file-line-error --halt-on-error --tex=latex`.

Comment: I too, but the output gets mangled, at least when opened with Firefox or Safari. Oh, and the same if I use PS output and convert to PDF

Comment: @egreg, If you remove the line `dotlabel`, is the output better? What if you replace the `TEX(...)` with `btex ... etex`?

Comment: Updated `TL2013` results in `svg` output that looks OK in `Firefox` (both `Win7` and `Linux`).
Have you considered to use RAM-disk to speed things up?

Answer (score 3):

The slowness here is nothing to do with the SVG output format.  You get the same slowness with the `TEX()` macro with regular PostScript output.   The problem is the implementation of the `TEX()` macro.  It works by writing a string out to a file, and then closing the file, and reading the file back in. This lets you concatenate regular MP strings before you pass them to TeX; something you can not do with `btex ... etex`.
It is slow because it does this for every label.

But if you unwrap the macro a bit, it is possible to use the write-to-file-close-and-then-read-back technique directly using the MP primitives.  Then you can write all the labels to one file, and process it in a single pass through TeX (or LaTeX).  This is much faster if you have many labels.

Here is an example (in SVG format):

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.svg";
outputformat := "svg";

beginfig(1);

n:=26;
R:=100;

  path p; 
  p = for t=0 step 360/n until 360: right scaled R rotated t -- endfor cycle;
  draw p;

  for i=0 upto n-1:
      fill fullcircle scaled dotlabeldiam shifted point i of p;
      write "label(btex $" & char (65+i) & "_0$ etex, (" 
          & decimal (1.12 xpart (point i of p)) & "," 
          & decimal (1.12 ypart (point i of p)) & "));" to ".mplabels";
  endfor
  write EOF to ".mplabels";
  input .mplabels;

endfig;
end.
```

This produces this image (converted to PNG for display here...)

[image]

MP has produced 26 separate dynamic labels, but it runs just as fast as if I was just doing one label.

- Note the slightly fussy syntax: `write "string" to "file"` needs the file as a proper `string`, but `input` just wants an identifier without the `"` marks.
- `EOF` is a built in value that writes an EOF marker to a file in order to close it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the [*latexmp* package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexmp)?  To quote:

> The MetaPost pack­age la­texMP im­ple­ments a user-friendly in­ter­face to ac­cess LaTeX-based type­set­ting ca­pa­bil­i­ties in MetaPost. The text to be type­set is given as string. This al­lows even dy­namic text el­e­ments, for ex­am­ple coun­ters, to be used in la­bels. Com­pared to other im­ple­men­ta­tions it is much more flex­i­ble, since it can be used as di­rect re­place­ment for btex..etex, and much faster, com­pared for ex­am­ple to the so­lu­tion pro­vided by tex.mp

Comment: It seems not to work well with svg output, though.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that METAPOST has added explicit support for outputting SVGs since v1.8 (see the manual for details).

Comment: How does this answer the original question?

Comment: It points out that the original limitation of METAPOST not directly making SVGs is no longer present.

Comment: I think the question was about why calling TEX() repeatedly is slow. The svg output is beside the point. And anyway I think the op was using a version of mp that already supported svg natively.